# php FILTER_VALIDATE_URL giving unexpected result

Tags: php

my Worketc account URL : `akhilesh.worketc.com`.

But PHP function `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL` gives this URL as a invalid url.

So is there any alternate way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

Add Protocol to it. i.e. append `http`/`https`/`ftp` etc. to your url before testing.

```
var_dump(filter_var('http://akhilesh.worketc.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL));
```

**FILTER_VALIDATE_URL**

> > Validates value as URL (according to » http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396), optionally with required components. Beware a valid URL may not specify the HTTP protocol http:// so further validation may be required to determine the URL uses an expected protocol, e.g. ssh:// or mailto:. Note that the function will only find ASCII URLs to be valid; internationalized domain names (containing non-ASCII characters) will fail.

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)

Comment: i need to check that if input url is akhilesh.worketc.com then append 'http://' to it otherwise not. Is there any proper way to implement it

Comment: Atleast 100 ways that I know off, do some research to find out how to check if some word exists in a string, and if it doesn't then append it